# How do i getting start with ROS?

Tags: ros, arduino

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just beginner of Arduino.
So i don't understand your Documentation
Do you have another way to learning ROS?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33350/how-do-i-getting-start-with-ros?/) by [pacozaa](https://answers.ros.org/users/2320/pacozaa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-05-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please start with the [tutorials](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials), then if you have questions, please ask.

---

Originally posted by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) with karma: 2962 on 2012-05-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4